# How to create alert when indicator color changes pine script

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to create an alert when the indicator color turns from red to green and vis versa. I am not familiar with the needed code to do so. Can someone help me what to be added to the indicator code to generate this alert?

```
//@version=4
//[SHK] STC colored indicator
//https://www.tradingview.com/u/shayankm/

study(title="[SHK] Schaff Trend Cycle (STC)", shorttitle="STC", overlay=false)
EEEEEE=input(12,"Length")
BBBB=input(26,"FastLength")
BBBBB=input(50,"SlowLength")

AAAA(BBB, BBBB, BBBBB) =>
fastMA = ema(BBB, BBBB)
slowMA = ema(BBB, BBBBB)
AAAA = fastMA - slowMA
AAAA

AAAAA(EEEEEE, BBBB, BBBBB) => 
AAA=input(0.5)
var CCCCC = 0.0
var DDD = 0.0
var DDDDDD = 0.0
var EEEEE = 0.0
BBBBBB = AAAA(close,BBBB,BBBBB)     
CCC = lowest(BBBBBB, EEEEEE)
CCCC = highest(BBBBBB, EEEEEE) - CCC    
CCCCC := (CCCC > 0 ? ((BBBBBB - CCC) / CCCC) * 100 : nz(CCCCC[1])) 
DDD := (na(DDD[1]) ? CCCCC : DDD[1] + (AAA * (CCCCC - DDD[1]))) 
DDDD = lowest(DDD, EEEEEE) 
DDDDD = highest(DDD, EEEEEE) - DDDD     
DDDDDD := (DDDDD > 0 ? ((DDD - DDDD) / DDDDD) * 100 : nz(DDDDDD[1])) 
EEEEE := (na(EEEEE[1]) ? DDDDDD : EEEEE[1] + (AAA * (DDDDDD - EEEEE[1])))
EEEEE

mAAAAA = AAAAA(EEEEEE,BBBB,BBBBB)
mColor = mAAAAA > mAAAAA[1] ? color.new(color.green,20) : color.new(color.red,20)

plot(mAAAAA,color=mColor, title="STC",linewidth=2)

ul=plot(25,color=color.new(color.gray,70))
ll=plot(75,color=color.new(color.gray,70)) 
fill(ul,ll,color=color.new(color.gray,96))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Below line is where the color handling is done:

```
mColor = mAAAAA > mAAAAA[1] ? color.new(color.green,20) : color.new(color.red,20)
```

And the condition is `mAAAAA > mAAAAA[1]`. So you need to look for a state change in this condition.

Below code will do it:

```
mColor = mAAAAA > mAAAAA[1] ? color.new(color.green,20) : color.new(color.red,20)
_mColor = mAAAAA > mAAAAA[1]
alertcondition((not _mColor[1] and _mColor), "Red to Green", "Red to Green")
alertcondition((_mColor[1] and not _mColor), "Green to Red", "Green to Red")
```

Comment: Thank you very very much for prompt and acute response. It works very well.

Comment: One last question, if i want to add a line to check if the price is above 200 EMA line or below, what shall i add to the code? thanks a million in advance