# Need Help for creating a Braid Filter alert by changing Color (pine Script)

Tags: pine-script, braid

can you help me with the Pine Script?
The Braid Filter indicator is painting in 3 colors.

I need an alert for:

1. green bars change in red
2. red bars change in green
3. gray bars change in red
4. gray bars change in green

Thats my plot:
BraidColor = ma01 > ma02 and dif > filter ? color.green : ma02 > ma01 and dif > filter ? color.red : color.gray

Thx for help.

I have tryed some thing alert from "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71015467/how-to-create-alert-when-indicator-color-changes-pine-script "

but it doesn't work well.

Thx.

Comment: Ui...Sry for that vitruvius.

Comment: Here my script:

Comment: `//-- Plots
BraidColor = ma01 > ma02 and dif > filter ? color.green : ma02 > ma01 and dif > filter ? color.red : color.gray

plot(dif, "Braid", BraidColor, 5, plot.style_columns)
plot(filter, "Filter", color.blue, 2, plot.style_line)
bgcolor(BraidColor)

mColor = ma01 > ma02[1] and dif > filter ? color.new(color.green,20) : ma02 > ma01 and dif > filter ? color.new(color.red,20) : color.gray
_mColor = ma01 > ma02[1] 
alertcondition((not _mColor[1] and _mColor), "Red to Green", "Red to Green")
alertcondition((_mColor[1] and not _mColor), "Green to Red", "Green to Red")`

Comment: I need help to better differentiate the color. the alarm shall trigger when from gray to green or red and when green to red or red to green.

Answer (score 0):

to make the code cleaner, separate the colors

```
bGreen   = (ma01 > ma02 and dif > filter)
bRed     = (ma02 > ma01 and dif > filter)
bGray    = not bGreen and not bRed
```

And now you can create clearer rules in your alerts

```
alertcondition((not bGreen[1] and bRed), "Green to Red", "Green to Red")
alertcondition((not bRed[1] and bGreen), "Red to Green", "Red to Green")
alertcondition((not bGray[1] and bRed), "Gray to Red", "Gray to Red")
alertcondition((not bGray[1] and bGreen), "Gray to Green", "Gray to Green")
```

Comment: Hi and thx Gustavo Cardelle.

Comment: one thing is crazy. although the color of the indicator is the same, there is always a signal at the end of each bar

Comment: For example, although the indicator is red, the alarm throws green to red and gray to red for each additional red bar.

Comment: I'm just trying to go with the color now. Wouldn't that also be possible?

Comment: `alertcondition(BraidColor == color.green, "Bars turned green!", alert.bar, sound.bell)
alertcondition(BraidColor == color.red, "Bars turned red!", alert.bar, sound.bell)`

Comment: I hope I haven't overlooked anything`//-- Plots
BraidColor = ma01 > ma02 and dif > filter

plot(dif, "Braid", BraidColor ? color.green : color.red, 5, plot.style_columns)
plot(filter, "Filter", color.blue, 2, plot.style_line)
bgcolor(BraidColor ? color.green : color.red)

prevColor := nz(prevColor[1]) ? BraidColor : prevColor[1]

// -- Alarm
alertcondition(BraidColor and not prevColor, "Braid turned green!", "Braid turned green!")
alertcondition(not BraidColor and prevColor, "Braid turned red!", "Braid turned red!")`

Comment: oh no the gray color is gone now. Does somebody still have an idea?